# I'm an escape artist who am I?

Tags: riddle

This should be an easy riddle, hope you enjoy it!

> People want me dead,
>
> I've died and I came back,
>
> I've been cursed,
>
> and I stole many things,
>
> I'm an escape artist,
>
> I was born in India during a typhoon,
>
> my name has an animal in it.

**Question**: Who am I?

**HINT 1**:

> Not everyone around me is human. (friend or foe)

**HINT 2**:

> I've never been in an airplane.

**HINT 3**:

> I'm proud of my title.

Comment: I think it's about a hindu god, but can put my finger on it. I'm saying this based on your previous question. :). By the way, if you have more about mythology, bring them on. I love these riddles.

Comment: @Marius nope :) I added another hint if you dare to use it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you

> Captain Jack Sparrow

People want me dead,

> A lot of people want him dead during the movies

I've died and I came back,

> Part 3 of the movies

I've been cursed,

> first movie

and I stole many things,

> He is always stealing something in the movies

I'm an escape artist,

> He often escaped from prison or dangerous situations

I was born in India during a typhoon,

> He was born on a ship during a typhoon, not sure that it was in india, but could be possible

my name has an animal in it.

> Sparrow

Extra hints:

> An undead Ape is always around, no planes at this time, Captain is important...

Comment: This is the correct answer :)

Comment: @Decypher was India the name of the ship?

Comment: @Abhishek Look on the dutch wikipedia for the character under young years bio Quote: 'is de zoon van XXXXXXXX en werd geboren in Indië tijdens een tyfoon.' Means: Is the son of XXXXX and was born in India during a typhoon. I'm not sure if it was on a ship or not.

Comment: @Decypher maybe it was the West Indies , you know the Caribbean , good fun anywaY :)

Answer (score 8):

It is most likely not this but:
Are you...

> Mad Cow disease

People want me dead,

> People want to get rid of the disease

I've died and I came back,

> The disease kills and comes back in another host

I've been cursed,

> Because you bring no good

and I stole many things,

> Stole many lives

I'm an escape artist,

> The disease is hidden in the host

I was born in India during a typhoon,

> This I don't know

my name has an animal in it.

> Cow

Comment: No sorry, I'm looking for a person not a disease

Comment: Yes, but creative answer deserve upvotes as well :)

Comment: [It has been theorised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bovine_spongiform_encephalopathy#:~:text=Alan%20Colchester%2C%20a,further%20investigation.%5B66%5D) that this disease actually originates from India.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> SoFloAntonio

---

People want me dead

> Lots of people want him dead due to his abuse of copyright in his YouTube videos

I've died and I came back

> His YouTube channel was temporarily deleted, but it was reinstated

I've been cursed

> Same explanation as the first line

And I stole many things

> He is known to reupload other people's videos and claim them as his own

I'm an escape artist

> Has managed to avoid being in a lot of trouble with the law for unknown reasons, he has been accused and significant evidence has been staged against him but he still hasn't gotten in any real trouble for his actions

I was born in India during a typhoon

> I'm not sure about this one, I don't know where he was born

My name has an animal in it

> ANT is in SoFloANTonio

Comment: Not the answer that I was looking for. Also he's born in the Maryland - US not India

Comment: Ah well, it was worth a shot

Comment: Don't give up, keep trying!

Comment: @Decypher where exactly was he born ?

Comment: @Abhishek I can only tell India.(during a typhoon)

Comment: nice try but the place of birth didnt match

Comment: Qbone +1 :), you know who I am

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

> Cavein Cuevas Caramol

People want me dead,

> His mother couldn't move when water started to come in their house

I've died and I came back,

> Don't know

I've been cursed,

> Don't know

and I stole many things,

> Don't know

I'm an escape artist,

> "Going out" of his mother through birth ?

I was born in India during a typhoon,

> Yes

my name has an animal in it.

> ram

Source :

> http://news.trust.org//item/20141106074931-m4jnx/

Comment: Not the person I'm looking for